# Condition on sides of triangle to proof it is isoceles

Tags: inequality, triangles

Let $$ a\geq b \geq c > 0 $$ be real numbers such that for all $$n $$ element of natural number , there exists triangles of side length $$ a^n , b^n , c^n.  $$ Prove that the triangles are isosceles .

I tried taking derivatives and proving that there will exist some $n$ at which inequality would stop holding. But it is not working out.

Also I tried substituting triangle inequalities for $n=1$ ; but it is of no use I guess.

I think binomial maybe of some use. I tried completing the binomial of $a^n + b^n$. But I am not able to use it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the triangle with sides $a,b,c$ were not isosceles, then $a>b>c>0$. Then, for $n$ sufficiently big, $a^n>b^n+c^n$, against the assumption that $a^n,b^n$ and $c^n$ are the lengths of the sides of a triangle. It means that at least one equality of $a\geq b\geq c$ must hold (actually, we can even say that $a=b$).

Comment: How do you proove that for n sufficiently big a^n > b^n  +c^n  holds??

Comment: @KavitaJuneja $a/b>1$, so $(a/b)^n\to\infty$. Take any $n$ with $(a/b)^n>2$, then $a^n>2b^n>b^n+c^n$.

Comment: Ohhhh.. got it thank you

Comment: It just slipped out of my eyes